# Email admin when post pending?

Tags: posts

I have this little bit of code that sends me an email whenever a new posts is published by an author, but I want to be alerted to posts in 'pending' status by contributors too.

```
add_action('publish_post', 'send_admin_email');
function send_admin_email($post_id){
    $to = 'myemail@email.com';
    $subject = 'New Post on The Articist';
    $message = "new post published at: ".get_permalink($post_id);
    wp_mail($to, $subject, $message );
}
```

Can I have emails sent to me so I'm informed when posts are pending?

Code from userabuser's first solution, this doesn't seem to actually send emails(yes, I have changed it to my actual email address in the functions.php).

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'pending_post_status', 10, 3 );

function pending_post_status( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {

    if ( $new_status === "pending" ) {
        function send_pending_email($post_id){
            $to = 'myemailaddresshere@mysite.com';
            $subject = 'New Pending Post';
            $message = "new post Pending";

            wp_mail($to, $subject, $message );
           }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There a couple of ways you can go about it depending on your use case and although example number 1 is perfectly valid, it might make more sense to employ the use of example number 2.

### Example #1:

This will send you an email each time a post is updated/published with the status of "pending". This will also email you if the status was already "pending" and the user hits save as pending again.

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'pending_post_status', 10, 3 );

function pending_post_status( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {

    if ( $new_status === "pending" ) {

        wp_mail(
            //your arguments here...
        );
    }

}
```

### Example #2:

This will send you an email when a post is updated or published as pending only IF the previous status of the post was not already set to pending.

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'pending_post_status', 10, 3 );

function pending_post_status( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {

    if ( $new_status === "pending" && $old_status !== "pending" ) {

        wp_mail(
            //your arguments here...
        );
    }

}
```

*Choose your poison...*

Additional resources:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions

Comment: Hi userabuser, I edited my first post to reflect your answer. (I can't get it to work, I'm sure I'm doing it right though).

Comment: ...actually you are doing it wrong, what you have done is nested a function within a function BUT then you fail to call your nested function `send_pending_email` so while the conditional statement `if ( $new_status === "pending" )` is evaluating to `TRUE`, nothing happens because `send_pending_email` doesn't get called. Remove the inner function `send_pending_email` as it's not needed.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress has a hook transition_post_status that might help. Take a look at http://blog.joshschumacher.com/2011/10/11/wordpress-transition_post_status-action/ for documentation on its usage.